# The provided host name is not valid for this server

Tags: 8, installation

I'm trying to migrate a drupal website from a server into my localhost but I trigger the error

> The provided host name is not valid for this server.

I've seen I need to add the trusted host pattern, but looks like this is not working I still get the error

My server is run on port 9000

```
sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:9000
```

My trusted hosts, and I've no Vhost

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^serverStuffWeDontMind$',
  '^localhost\:9000$',
);
```

Comment: Why don't you add `^127\.0\.0\.1$` or `^127\.0\.0\.1\:9000$` to this array?!

Comment: I already tried to  add `^127\.0\.0\.1\:9000$` but I still get the error

Comment: Why don't you say this in your question then? Have you also flushed caches multiple times? Do you maybe have OPcache or some other server side caching enabled? And what's with just `^127\.0\.0\.1$` and just `^localhost$`? And what happens when you completely remove this setting?

Comment: Because it looks to me localhost and the ip is the same so I didn't see the point. I've done nothing more than adding the trusted host and launching the server with the php command. I don't know yet drupal enough to know if there is some cache file I need to clean and the way of doing it.

Comment: An IP and a domain name are __not__ the same. Blindly trusting all domain names on the same IP in a shared hosting environment would be a fiasco.

Comment: Looks like removing all the array solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a dev - env, simply add

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']];
```

But never do this in production.

Comment: Or remove `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` completely.